# Where do I get the .map file for a .min css styles of Font awesome in version 5.3.1

Tags: css, frontend, font-awesome, source-maps, font-awesome-5

I had inherited an old project at work that uses the Font Awesome library on version 5.3.1.

The CSS file that comes with the library is called `font-awesome.min.css` and as you can tell from the extension is a miniaturized version of the CSS, which basically means that all the CSS styles are in a single line, which makes it almost impossible to read.

AFAIK, a `.min` usually comes with a `.map` file that sets the rules to translate the `.min` file to a readable version of the CSS file. That is why I am looking for the `.map` file for this version of Font Awesome (5.3.1) but I can not find it on the Internet.

I had tried these official websites with no luck:

- https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/releases/tag/5.3.1
- https://fontawesome.com/v5/download

I did not see the `.map` file in the official release.

¿Is there any way to generate this file? Working with the miniaturized version is very uncomfortable.

Also, I would like to know if my question does make sense or if I do need to know other stuff related to my question. I have a few experience with front-end, and I already had this problem with `.js` files also miniaturized, but I managed to find the `.map`s for them. It seems that the old owner of the project did not care about working with `.min` files...

Comment: A more common term is "minified".